# How to cite Processing software

Tags: processing

I'm trying to find a way to cite Processing software http://www.processing.org/ But I am not sure how to do. 
Any Help ??

Comment: do you mean like how to google it without a whole bunch or irrelevant material popping up? You can try "p5"

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you mean referencing it in a scientific publication. You can either simply use the URL, and do that according to whatever citation style you are using. Or, probably better, you can cite one of the publications by Casey Reas and Ben Fry. There are plenty. Depending on the topic of your publication you might for instance cite:

*Reas, C. and Fry, B. Processing: programming for the media arts (2006). Journal AI & Society, volume 20(4), pages 526-538, Springer*

By the way, some libraries do have publications too. The map library Unfolding, which I believe you are using, asks you to cite:

*Nagel, T., Klerkx, J., Vande Moere, A., Duval, E. Unfolding - A Library for Interactive Maps, Human Factors in Computing and Informatics, Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 7946, 2013, pp 497-513, Springer*